# Uploading Avatar on Parse (using AngularParse Service)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
{"name":"tfss-4dde4ec8-e678-495a-a5d0-d3e51f0bdafc-search-pic-img6.jpg","url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/d130ccda-cf9f-4264-999e-09305bed0fd1/tfss-4dde4ec8-e678-495a-a5d0-d3e51f0bdafc-search-pic-img6.jpg"}
```

This is the return Object, When I upload the file on the parse server. I want to use this object to store it on the Parse Class avatar column as type "file" not string. In short I am trying to store it as image file after uploading. I want to do it in Cloud Code javascript rather than on html javacript. I want to send the object to parse and store it as image file.

Here's my cloud code. I am new to parse a bit.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("editProfileweb", function(request) {
  var avatar = request.object;
  var user = request.user;
if (user) {
    user.set("avatar",avatar);
    user.save(null, {
    success: function(user) {
        response.success();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
        response.success();
    }
});
} else {
    response.error("User not authenticated");
}  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
Object.set({columnName: {"name": File.name, "url": File.url, "__type": "File"}});
```